# Rails - Sinatra real time notifications

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, notifications, sinatra

I am trying to build a real time notifications module that functions in a similar manner to facebook's realtime notifications for example if a user requests friendship of another user a push notification is sent to the second one where I have the following constraints:
1- notifications are sent to a specific user's all browser instances
2- user need to be logged in to subscribe him to notifications
3- not to use pooling because of performance issues
4- it obviously need to be secure

I did a quick research and I found out that the options I have are web sockets or server-sent events. server-sent events handles reconnecting automatically and quite fits the functionality I needed so I decided to go with it.

I built a sinatra event driven server where whenever a user requests friendship of another user the notification should be pushed through it to the second user but there appeared to be several problems where my solutions to it convinced me that I am going in the wrong direction.

How do I bind an eventsource to a specific user and at the same time maintain security. What is the proper way I can create an eventsource if and only if a user is logged in.

I also need general helpful guidelines to address this task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with the server sent events for automatic re-connectivity and the usage of http and no special protocols. Besides I thought that I do not really need bidirectional full duplex connection for this afterall this is not a chat applications so I did the following:

The sinatra server listens to connections and associates the specific connection recieved to the id of the user making it and so I can aggregate connections based on the user ID which then opens some vulnerabilities which I tried to handle and will talk about later.

```
get '/connect/:user_id', provides: 'text/event-stream' do
    headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => "#{domainname.whatever.com}"
    stream :keep_open do |connection|
        connections << {'connection': connection, 'user_id': params[:user_id]}
        connection.callback {
            connections.select {|out| out[:connection]==connection} do |e| connections.delete e end 
        }
    end 
end
```

When an event that triggers a notification happens, after executing the events logic I send a post request to the Sinatra notification server along with a hash function of secret key, userid, time . The Sinatra server recomputes the hash to guarantee that it has been sent via our source. The Sinatra server then pushes the notification to all the connections associated with the user id in the "to" field of the notification params which are listening via eventsource.

using `eventsource.onmessage` I do DOM changes to show the recieved notificaiton.

Now it is working greatly.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you don't need to have "exactly real time" and you can use setTimeout(simulate_realtime, 5000); that checks if there is new data on the server each 5 seconds.

You can also checkout https://github.com/rails/actioncable that will be in Rails 5, which will be release a stable this fall. You can bet on it, it is the next main component that will be added to rails.

Comment: This is not what I am after .. I need a persistent connection where a server will send data to the client whenever there exists a notification

Comment: I think you should use websockets, action cable is built on top of it

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need eventmachine(https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/tree/master/examples/guides/getting_started). Look at the chat example